# Apache PIG - How can I display the execution time of a script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

Is there any possibility to show the whole execution time of a PIG script?
The best thing would be to generate a separate file which contains the total time (e.g. hh:mm:s) taken to execute the script.

Please give me a PIG code example to realize this.

Answer (score 0):

**Timing your UDFs**

The first step to improving performance and efficiency is measuring
 where the time is going. Pig provides a light-weight method for
 approximately measuring how much time is spent in different
 user-defined functions (UDFs) and Loaders. Simply set the
 pig.udf.profile property to true. This will cause new counters to be
 tracked for all Map-Reduce jobs generated by your script:
 approx_microsecs measures the approximate amount of time spent in a
 UDF, and approx_invocations measures the approximate number of times
 the UDF was invoked. Note that this may produce a large number of
 counters (two per UDF). Excessive amounts of counters can lead to poor
 JobTracker performance, so use this feature carefully, and preferably
 on a test cluster.

You can view all your job counters in resource manager web UI.

From - https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html

Answer (score 0):

a = load '/mapred/history/done' using HadoopJobHistoryLoader() as (j:map[], m:map[], r:map[]);
b = foreach a generate j#'PIG_SCRIPT_ID' as id, j#'USER' as user, j#'JOBNAME' as script_name, 
         (Long) j#'SUBMIT_TIME' as start, (Long) j#'FINISH_TIME' as end;
c = group b by (id, user, script_name)
d = foreach c generate group.user, group.script_name, (MAX(b.end) - MIN(b.start)/1000;
dump d;

Comment: Thank you for the script, but I always get: 2015-05-01 13:49:25,633 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve HadoopJobHistoryLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Also I don´t have any /mapred/history/done path.

Comment: Just check whether you have piggybank.jar in your classpath or try to register the piggbank.jar in your pig script...You can either check  hadoop.job.history.location or mapred.job.tracker.history.completed.location property to find the path of the history files...